# Calling Command Line From Blue Prism

Tags: command-line, blueprism

I am trying to use Nitro PDF Reader from the command line.
This was working correctly, but I am now getting an error Internal : Could not execute code stage: Ambiguous match found.
Passing null values also produces this error.

Code:

```
timedOut = False
Dim startTime as Date = Date.Now

Dim info as New ProcessStartInfo(appn)
If args <> "" Then  info.Arguments = args
If dir <> "" Then info.WorkingDirectory = dir

Using proc As Process = Process.Start(info)
timedOut = Not proc.WaitForExit( _
 CInt(timeout.TotalMilliseconds))
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue looked to be caused by another action with similar code. There was an action called Run Process until Ended. I then duplicated to have a second which was called Run Process.

This was causing the error.